# How to manage UITableView + Dynamic Custom Cell(UIBUtton + UITextField + UIBUtton) Insertion?

Tags: ios4, uitableview, uitextfield, custom-cell

I am having problem in managing UITableView. I 'm posting a screenshot here to briefly explain the problem. Image 1 shows the default View when First Time view Appears. When I tap on yellow button(Yellow Button is in a custom table section header view) I open an UIAlertView with table in it like shown in the image 2[image: image 2]. Then selecting any option I insert a custom cell with a button,textfield and another button. I have a mutable Array for each section so when I select an option I add that string into the corresponding section array and reloadtable.See image 3[image: image 3]. Now when I enter values in UITextfields the values replaced by another cells. See the two images below for understanding the problem. image 4[image: image 4]. Also when I delete a cell and insert a new the textfield is preloaded with previous value.

[image: Image 1]

And here is the .m file implementation code for analyze the problem

```
#import "contactsViewController.h"
#import "textFieldCell.h"
#import "SBTableAlert.h"
#import "PhoneFieldCell.h"
#import "DHValidation.h"

#define kTextFieldTag 222
#define kTitleButtonTag 111
#define MAX_LENGTH 20
#define charecterLimit 13
#define PHONE_NUMBER @"0123456789+-"

@implementation contactsViewController

@synthesize currentTextField;
@synthesize choiceList;
@synthesize labelHeaders;
@synthesize selectedIndexPath;
@synthesize aTable;
@synthesize customText;
@synthesize currentSelectionType;
@synthesize phoneList;
@synthesize emailList;
@synthesize otherDetailsList;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Prepare array's for display in table header and in custom alert option table
    [self prepareDataForTable];
    [self initializeProperties];

    //Set selected index to -1 by default
    selectedIndex = -1;
}

//prepare array's for table
- (void) prepareDataForTable {
    NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"work",@"home",@"mobile",@"custom",nil];
    self.choiceList = temp;
    [temp release];

    NSArray *temp1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First Name",@"Last Name",nil];
    self.labelHeaders = temp1;
    [temp1 release];
}


- (void) initializeProperties {
    //Initialize Mutable array's

    NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    self.phoneList = temp;
    [temp release];

    NSMutableArray *temp1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    self.emailList = temp1;
    [temp1 release];

    NSMutableArray *temp2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    self.otherDetailsList = temp2;
    [temp2 release];    
}


#pragma mark -

- (IBAction) btnCancelTapped:(id) sender {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction) btnDoneTapped:(id) sender { 

    [self.currentTextField resignFirstResponder];

    //TODO: Fetch all the data from all the cells and notify the delegate.
    NSMutableDictionary *allSectionsData = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autorelease];
    NSMutableDictionary *section1Dictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autorelease];
    NSMutableDictionary *phoneSectionDictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autorelease];
    NSMutableDictionary *emailSectionDictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autorelease];
    NSMutableDictionary *otherSectionDictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autorelease];

    //For Section 0
    for (unsigned rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 2; rowIndex++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

        cell = (textFieldCell*)[aTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITextField *txtf = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:kTextFieldTag];

        //TextField validation
        DHValidation *validation = [[DHValidation alloc] init];
        NSString *str =  [txtf.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        NSString *alertMessage = nil;

        BOOL isvalid = NO;
        if(![validation validateNotEmpty:str])
            alertMessage = @"NameField should not be Empty";
        else 
            isvalid = TRUE;

        if(!isvalid){
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:alertMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert  release];
            return ;
        }
        [validation release];

        NSString *type = nil;
        NSString *value = nil;

        if(rowIndex == 0)
            type = @"First Name";
        else if(rowIndex == 1){
            type = @"Last Name";
        }
        value = txtf.text;
        if(!value){ 
            //Do not insert that value in the dictinary
            value = @"";
        }else {
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:type,@"type",value,@"value",nil];
            [section1Dictionary setObject:dictionary forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rowIndex]];
        }
    }
    if([section1Dictionary count] > 0) {
        [allSectionsData setObject:section1Dictionary forKey:@"PersonalDetailsSection"];
    }



    //For Section 1
    for (unsigned rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < [phoneList count]; rowIndex++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:1];
        UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

        cell = (PhoneFieldCell*)[aTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        UITextField *txtf = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:kTextFieldTag];

        UIButton *btnTitle = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:kTitleButtonTag];
        NSString *type = nil;
        NSString *value = nil;

        type = [btnTitle currentTitle];
        value = [txtf text];

        if(!value || [[value stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""] ){
            //Do not insert that value in the dictinary
            continue;
        }else {
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:type,@"type",value,@"value",nil];
            [phoneSectionDictionary setObject:dictionary forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rowIndex]];
            //[phoneSectionDictionary setObject:value forKey:type];
        }
    }
    if([phoneSectionDictionary count] > 0) {
        [allSectionsData setObject:phoneSectionDictionary forKey:@"PhoneSection"];
    }

    //For Section 2 
    for (unsigned rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < [emailList count]; rowIndex++) {


        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:2];

        UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

        cell = (PhoneFieldCell*)[aTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        UITextField *txtf = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:kTextFieldTag];
        UIButton *btnTitle = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:kTitleButtonTag];
        NSString *type = nil;
        NSString *value = nil;


        type = [btnTitle currentTitle];
        value = [txtf text];


        if(!value || [[value stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""] ){
            //Do not insert that value in the dictinary
            continue;
        }else {
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:type,@"type",value,@"value",nil];
            [emailSectionDictionary setObject:dictionary forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rowIndex]];
        }
    }
    if([emailSectionDictionary count] > 0) {
        [allSectionsData setObject:emailSectionDictionary forKey:@"EmailSection"];
    }

    //for Section 3
    for (unsigned rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < [phoneList count]; rowIndex++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:3];
        UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

        cell = (PhoneFieldCell*)[aTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        UITextField *txtf = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:kTextFieldTag];

        UIButton *btnTitle = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:kTitleButtonTag];
        NSString *type = nil;
        NSString *value = nil;

        type = [btnTitle currentTitle];
        value = [txtf text];

        if(!value || [[value stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""] ){
            //Do not insert that value in the dictinary
            continue;
        }else {
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:type,@"type",value,@"value",nil];
            [otherSectionDictionary setObject:dictionary forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rowIndex]];
            //[phoneSectionDictionary setObject:value forKey:type];
        }
    }
    if([otherSectionDictionary count] > 0) {
        [allSectionsData setObject:otherSectionDictionary forKey:@"OtherSection"];
    }
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableView Data Source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 4;
}

// Returns the number of rows in a given section.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSInteger count = 0;
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            count = 2;
            break;
        case 1://Phone
            count = [phoneList count];
            break;
        case 2://Email
            count = [emailList count];
            break;
        case 3://Other
            count = [otherDetailsList count];
            break;
        default:
            count = 0;
            break;
    }
    return count;
}

// Returns the cell for a given indexPath.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"textFieldCustomCell";
    static NSString *PhoneFieldCustomCellIdentifier = @"PhoneFieldCustomCell";
    static NSString *EmailFieldCustomCellIdentifier = @"EmailFieldCustomCell";
    static NSString *OtherDetailsCustomCellIdentifier = @"OtherDetailsCustomCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:{
                cell = (textFieldCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                if (cell == nil) {
                    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"textFieldCell" owner:self options:nil];

                    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
                        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[textFieldCell class]]){
                            cell =  (textFieldCell *) currentObject;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
        case 1:{
            cell = (PhoneFieldCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PhoneFieldCustomCellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PhoneFieldCell" owner:self options:nil];

                for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
                    if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[PhoneFieldCell class]]){
                        cell =  (PhoneFieldCell *) currentObject;
                        ((PhoneFieldCell *)cell).enterText.delegate = self;
                        ((PhoneFieldCell *)cell).enterText.text = nil;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

            break;
        case 2:{
            cell = (EmailFieldCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:EmailFieldCustomCellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EmailFieldCell" owner:self options:nil];

                for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
                    if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[EmailFieldCell class]]){
                        cell =  (EmailFieldCell *) currentObject;
                        ((EmailFieldCell *)cell).enterText.delegate = self;
                        ((EmailFieldCell *)cell).enterText.text = nil;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

            break;
        case 3:{
            cell = (OtherDetailsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:OtherDetailsCustomCellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OtherDetailsCell" owner:self options:nil];

                for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
                    if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[OtherDetailsCell class]]){
                        cell =  (OtherDetailsCell *) currentObject;
                        ((OtherDetailsCell *)cell).enterText.delegate = self;
                        ((OtherDetailsCell *)cell).enterText.text = nil;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    //Setup cell data


    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:{
                ((textFieldCell*)cell).aTextField.delegate = self;
                if(indexPath.row == 0){
                    ((textFieldCell*)cell).aTextField.placeholder = @"Enter First Name";
                }
                if(indexPath.row == 1){
                    ((textFieldCell*)cell).aTextField.placeholder = @"Enter Last Name";
                }
                ((textFieldCell*)cell).aLabel.text = [self.labelHeaders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];           
            }
            break;
        case 1:{
                NSString *str = [phoneList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [((PhoneFieldCell *)cell).changeBtn setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [((PhoneFieldCell *)cell).changeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                ((PhoneFieldCell *)cell).btnDeleteCell.tag = indexPath.row;
                [((PhoneFieldCell *)cell).btnDeleteCell addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            }
            break;
        case 2:{
                NSString *str = [emailList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [((EmailFieldCell *)cell).changeBtn setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [((EmailFieldCell *)cell).changeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                ((EmailFieldCell *)cell).btnDeleteCell.tag = indexPath.row;
                [((EmailFieldCell *)cell).btnDeleteCell addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            }
            break;
        case 3:{
                NSString *str = [otherDetailsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [((OtherDetailsCell *)cell).changeBtn setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [((OtherDetailsCell *)cell).changeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                ((OtherDetailsCell *)cell).btnDeleteCell.tag = indexPath.row;
                [((OtherDetailsCell *)cell).btnDeleteCell addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30;
}
- (UIView*) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView viewForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger) section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self headerViewForSection:section];

}

// Handle row selection
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}



- (UIView*) headerViewForSection:(NSInteger)section {

    CGRect lblTitleFrame = CGRectMake(15, 0, 200, 20);
    CGRect btnFrame = CGRectMake(280.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0);
    CGRect headerViewFrame = CGRectMake(0,0, 40, 30);

    NSString *lblTitleText = nil;

    switch (section) {
        case 1://phone
            lblTitleText = @"Phone";
            break;
        case 2://email
            lblTitleText = @"Email";

            break;
        case 3://other details
            lblTitleText = @"Other";

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    //Create a header view with a label and a button

    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerViewFrame] autorelease];

    UILabel *titleForTable = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:lblTitleFrame];
    titleForTable.text = lblTitleText;
    titleForTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleForTable.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    titleForTable.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [headerView addSubview:titleForTable];
    [titleForTable release];

    UIButton *phoneButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:btnFrame];
    phoneButton.alpha = 0.7;
    phoneButton.tag = section;
    [phoneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    [phoneButton addTarget: self action: @selector(headerTapped:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [headerView addSubview: phoneButton];
    [phoneButton release];

    return headerView;  
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITextField Delegate
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.currentTextField = textField;
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
//textfield charecters range
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField.text.length >= MAX_LENGTH && range.length == 0){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"You reached maximum limit - 20" 
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert  release];
        return NO; // return NO to not change text
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}

#pragma mark -
- (void)deleteButtonTapped:(id)sender{

    if([self.currentTextField isFirstResponder]) {
        [self.currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }


    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");

    UIButton *btnDelete = (UIButton*)sender;
    id cell = [[btnDelete superview] superview];

    if([cell isKindOfClass:[PhoneFieldCell class]]) {
        cell = (PhoneFieldCell*)cell;
    }
    if([cell isKindOfClass:[EmailFieldCell class]]) {
        cell = (EmailFieldCell*)cell;
    }
    if([cell isKindOfClass:[OtherDetailsCell class]]) {
        cell = (OtherDetailsCell*)cell;
    }


    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [aTable indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"Section is %d and row is %d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 1:
            [self.phoneList removeObjectAtIndex:[btnDelete tag]];
            [aTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self.emailList removeObjectAtIndex:[btnDelete tag]];
            [aTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            break;
        case 3:
            [self.otherDetailsList removeObjectAtIndex:[btnDelete tag]];
            [aTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [aTable reloadData];
}

- (void)changeButtonTapped:(id)sender{

    if([self.currentTextField isFirstResponder]) {
        [self.currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }

    UIButton *btnDelete = (UIButton*)sender;
    id cell = (PhoneFieldCell*)[[btnDelete superview] superview];

    if([cell isKindOfClass:[PhoneFieldCell class]]) {
        cell = (PhoneFieldCell*)cell;
    }
    if([cell isKindOfClass:[EmailFieldCell class]]) {
        cell = (EmailFieldCell*)cell;
    }
    if([cell isKindOfClass:[OtherDetailsCell class]]) {
        cell = (OtherDetailsCell*)cell;
    }

    self.selectedIndexPath = [aTable indexPathForCell:cell];
    shouldModify = YES;

    NSLog(@"Section is %d and row is %d",self.selectedIndexPath.section,self.selectedIndexPath.row);


    SBTableAlert *alert = nil;      
     alert  = [[[SBTableAlert alloc] initWithTitle:@"Options" cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" messageFormat:@"Select your option!"] autorelease];
    [alert setType:SBTableAlertTypeSingleSelect];
    [alert.view addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert setDataSource:self];
    [alert show];
}



- (void)headerTapped:(id)sender {

    if([self.currentTextField isFirstResponder]) {
        [self.currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }

    UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*)sender;

    //set current selection according to section
    switch ([tappedButton tag]) {
        case 1://Phone
            self.currentSelectionType = SELECTIONTYPE_PHONE;
            break;
        case 2://Email
            self.currentSelectionType = SELECTIONTYPE_EMAIL;
            break;
        case 3://Other details
            self.currentSelectionType = SELECTIONTYPE_OTHER;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    SBTableAlert *alert;        
    alert   = [[[SBTableAlert alloc] initWithTitle:@"Options" cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" messageFormat:@"Select your option!"] autorelease];
    [alert setType:SBTableAlertTypeSingleSelect];
    [alert.view addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert setDataSource:self];

    [alert show];
}




#pragma mark - SBTableAlertDataSource

- (UITableViewCell *)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert cellForRow:(NSInteger)row {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

    [cell.textLabel setText:[self.choiceList objectAtIndex:row]];
    if(row == selectedIndex)
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else {
        cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert {
    if (tableAlert.type == SBTableAlertTypeSingleSelect)
        return [self.choiceList count];
    else
        return 4;
}

#pragma mark - SBTableAlertDelegate

- (void)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row {
    if (tableAlert.type == SBTableAlertTypeMultipleSelct) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableAlert.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]];
        if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        else
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

        [tableAlert.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0] animated:YES];
    }
    else if (tableAlert.type == SBTableAlertTypeSingleSelect) {
        selectedIndex = row;
        [tableAlert.tableView reloadData];
        [tableAlert.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0] animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == 1){
    if(selectedIndex == -1){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select at least one choice" message:nil 
                                                delegate:nil 
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

    else if(cellSelected ==  FALSE){
        if(selectedIndex  == 3){
            UIAlertView *customAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter Custom Message" message:@"\n\n" 
                                                                 delegate:self 
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
            customAlert.tag = 99;

            CGAffineTransform myTransForm = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);
            UITextField *temp = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 50, 255, 30)];
            self.customText = temp;
            [temp release];
            self.customText.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            self.customText.placeholder = @"Enter Custom Text";
            self.customText.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            self.customText.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
            [customAlert addSubview:self.customText];
            [customAlert setTransform:myTransForm];

            [customAlert show];
            [customAlert release];

        }else {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableAlert.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[ NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0]];
            NSString *val = cell.textLabel.text;
            if(!shouldModify) {
                switch (self.currentSelectionType) {
                    case SELECTIONTYPE_PHONE:
                        [phoneList addObject:val];
                        break;
                    case SELECTIONTYPE_EMAIL:
                        [emailList addObject:val];
                        break;
                    case SELECTIONTYPE_OTHER:
                        [otherDetailsList addObject:val];
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }   
            }
            else {
                switch (self.selectedIndexPath.section) {
                    case 1:
                        [phoneList replaceObjectAtIndex:self.selectedIndexPath.row withObject:val];
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        [emailList replaceObjectAtIndex:self.selectedIndexPath.row withObject:val];
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        [otherDetailsList replaceObjectAtIndex:self.selectedIndexPath.row withObject:val];
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }   
                shouldModify = NO;
            }

        }

    }
    if(self.currentSelectionType != SELECTIONTYPE_UNKNOWN || self.selectedIndexPath.section > 0)
        [aTable reloadData];
    selectedIndex = -1;
    [tableAlert release];
    }
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if(alertView.tag == 99 && buttonIndex == 1){

            NSString *val = [self.customText text];
        if(!val || [[val stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""]){
                //show error alert here and return from here
                UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                     message:@"Please fill a value for custom text"
                                                                    delegate:nil
                                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [errorAlert show];
                [errorAlert release];
                return;
            }
            switch (self.currentSelectionType) {
                case SELECTIONTYPE_PHONE:
                    [phoneList addObject:val];
                    [aTable reloadData];
                    break;
                case SELECTIONTYPE_EMAIL:
                    [emailList addObject:val];
                    [aTable reloadData];
                    break;
                case SELECTIONTYPE_OTHER:
                    [otherDetailsList addObject:val];
                    [aTable reloadData];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }           
        }
}

#pragma mark -

/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.currentTextField = nil;

    self.choiceList = nil;
    self.labelHeaders = nil;

    self.selectedIndexPath = nil;
    self.aTable = nil;
    self.customText = nil;
    self.phoneList = nil;
    self.emailList = nil;
    self.otherDetailsList = nil;
    self.customText = nil;
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [phoneList release];
    [emailList release];
    [otherDetailsList release];
    [customText release];
    [customText release];
    [aTable release];
    [selectedIndexPath release];
    [choiceList release];
    [labelHeaders release];

    [currentTextField release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/01/04/elctextfieldcell-a-useful-tableviewcell-for-forms/

u can also manually do some customization according to your app need

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     [tableView reloadData];

  }
```

Comment: I Don't want to use another classes. I want to create my own. The Problem is just repeatability of textfield values and When I delete one row and insert a new the textfield comes with previous value prefilled

Comment: didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath here we can get the callback of editing so here we can reload data which will be new.ur problem is reusing the cell

Comment: please come to iphone/ipad room